# Los registros dejaron de guardarse en mi BD

Tags: php, base-de-datos, mariadb

soy nueva en esto de la programación php, estoy trabajando en una biblioteca virtual, y tengo un problema con la función de carga de los libros. Todo el resto de las funciones andan bien, menos la de agregar.
La tabla de datos tiene estos ítems:

```sql
  "titulo" varchar(150) COLLATE utf8mb4_spanish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  "autor" varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_spanish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  "anio" int(4) unsigned zerofill DEFAULT NULL,
  "pais" varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_spanish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  "editorial" varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_spanish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  "carrera" varchar(40) COLLATE utf8mb4_spanish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  "descripcion" varchar(400) COLLATE utf8mb4_spanish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  "disponibilidad" varchar(2) COLLATE utf8mb4_spanish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  "archivo" varchar(400) COLLATE utf8mb4_spanish_ci DEFAULT NULL.
```

La función de guardar está dividida en dos, en la primera parte se cargan todos los datos y en la segunda se guarda el enlace al archivo. 
Primera parte:

```php
<?php

    require 'conexion.php';

    $titulo = $_POST['inputTitle'];
    $autor = $_POST['inputAuthor'];
    $anio = $_POST['inputYear'];
    $pais = $_POST['inputCountry'];
    $editorial = $_POST['inputEditorial'];
    $carrera = $_POST['inputCareer'];
    $descripcion = $_POST['inputDesc'];
    $disponibilidad = $_POST['inputAvailability'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO mdl_library_books (titulo, autor, anio, pais, editorial, carrera, descripcion, disponibilidad) VALUES ('$titulo', '$autor', '$anio', '$pais', '$editorial', '$carrera', '$descripcion', '$disponibilidad')";
    $resultado=$conexion->query($sql);


    if($_FILES["libro"]["error"]>0){
        echo "Error al cargar archivo"; 
        } else {

        $nuevoTitulo = str_replace(' ', '-', $titulo);
        $ruta = "books/".$nuevoTitulo."/";
        $archivo = $ruta.$_FILES["libro"]["name"];

            if(!file_exists($ruta)){
                mkdir($ruta);
            }

            if(!file_exists($archivo)){

                $resultado = @move_uploaded_file($_FILES["libro"]["tmp_name"], $archivo);
            }

                if($resultado){
                    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.location.href='http://localhost:8080/malharro-library/library/guardarRuta.php?titulo=$titulo&archivo=$archivo';</script>";
                    } else {
                    echo "Error al guardar archivo";
                }
    }

    $conexion->close();

?>
```

Segunda parte:

```php
<?php

    require 'conexion.php';

    $titulo = $_GET['titulo'];
    $archivo = $_GET['archivo'];

    $sql = "UPDATE mdl_library_books SET archivo='$archivo' WHERE titulo = '$titulo'";
    $resultado = $conexion->query($sql);

    if($resultado){
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.location.href='http://localhost:8080/malharro-library/library/agregar.php';</script>";
    } else {
        echo "Error al guardar ruta de archivo";
    }

    $conexion->close();

?>
```

Aclaro que andaba perfectamente hace unos días, pero cuando lo volví a probar empezó a no guardar los registros, **los archivos si los guarda**, de la forma en que lo indique en el código, pero dejó de guardar los datos en la tabla de la DB.

Gracias.

Comment: Si haces un `SELECT * FROM mdl_library_books`, qué te aparece?

Comment: Para mostrar los datos (cuando andaba), hacia SELECT * FROM mdl_library_books y creaba una tabla en HTML con todos los datos. Ahora, cuando hago lo mismo no muestra nada, solo el encabezado de la tabla HTML.

Comment: No, me refiero a qué aparece cuando escribes `SELECT * FROM mdl_library_books` en el cliente de tu base de datos; cuando entras por consola o por un IDE o phpmyadmin o como sea?

Comment: Me dice que no hay registros.

Comment: ¿Puedes correr los `insert` y `update` en directamente en tu cliente?

Comment: Si, puedo insertar y actualizar los datos directamente en mi cliente, y de esa manera si los muestra.